# Oracle best way to overcome loop time

Tags: oracle, performance, loops, plsql

I have a code in which there is loop to process millions of records. Code looks like below:

```
FOR C1
 IN (SELECT a
     FROM tbl1
 WHERE <some conditions>)
LOOP

/*Some processing which took less than a sec to process a record*/

/*Call to procedures and functions.*/

END LOOP;
```

Above loop code can process around 9 records in 4 sec. I have millions of records to process through loop.

What is the best way to do this task?
Can I execute logic within the loop parallely?

Comment: The best way is paralellization but that must happen OUTSIDE the sql code.

Comment: Can you please update me on how can I convert this code in paralellization ?

Comment: can you please read what i wrote: as in: you do not do that in SQL - you basically open multiple connections and filter in the select to not select all (but a part in every connection). Then you can execute multipeol statements in parallel.

Comment: Even in parallel this will take an awesome lot of time if you have millions of records. And chances are parallel processing will introduce concurrency issues causing a less than hoped for improvement. Is there a chance you might be able to reduce the time needed for processing a single record?

Answer (score 2):

> "Can I execute logic within the loop parallely?"

Who can tell?  You haven't provided nearly enough information to go on.  I mean it's not even clear that the driving query is amenable to division into suitable chunks.

Parallelism might help but it's by no means guaranteed.  It depends how many CPUs you have, what other work is going on, and crucially the exact nature of the underlying process: if even one of those "Call to procedures and functions" issues a lock you have a fundamentally serial process.

> "What is the best way to do this task?

The general advice would be to lower the individual time for each record:

1. Do you need this as a row-by-row operation?  A set operation using pure SQL is likely to be way faster than a PL/SQL loop.  Again, this depends on the specifics of what you're doing.
2. Use PL/SQL profiling.  The Oracle [DBMS_HPROF tool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_hprof.htm#ARPLS66431) in 11g is a marvel when it comes to pinpointing where all the times goes.  Unfortunately it requires a DBA to grant access and create a directory object, but it's definitely worth raising an RFC for it.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_profiler.htm#ADFNS023).  (In earlier versions there's [DBMS_PROFILER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS878) which is a bit limited by still useful; it also requires DBA intervention).